# How to add a Share button in the persistent menu?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

In my messenger chatbot, I would like to add a Share button at the bottom in the persistent menu below 'Help' I could not find any documentation on how to do this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The persistent menu does not support the share button. The persistent menu is meant to be a way of navigating the bot. The share is meant for sharing specific message content, so their purpose is not really related.